# plotting raster layers after qmfit

Tags: r, gis

I have a rasterstack "prp_r" of RCM precipitation data and "prp_g" of GPM precipitation data:
`dimensions : 129, 135, 17415, 366  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)`
My aim is to plot the raster after bias correcting them by using "fitQmapQUANT".
My approach is the following:

1. I extracted the raster for one day prp_r[[1]] and converted it to dataframe. `r_df<-as.data.frame(prp_r[[1]],xy=T)`. Did same for GPM raster data and combined them.
   where
2. then used qmfit to get the bias corrected data:`qm2.fit <- fitQmapQUANT(r_df[3],r_df[4], qstep=0.01,nboot=1,wet.day=TRUE) qm2 <- doQmapQUANT(r_df[4],qm2.fit,type="tricub")`

I then convert back to raster to get the desired output.

This works fine for 1 but how do I do this for all the 366 layers? I can covert the entire rasterstack to dataframe but then doing qmfit columnwise for the respective columns in GPM and RCM has me confused if I'm approaching this the right way.
Also is there an alternative way to approach this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example based on what you mentioned, you will have to work around this:

```
#convert all rasters in rasterstack into dataframes
#If by combining you meant they have the same row length and cbind them
prpList <- mapply(function(x, y) data.frame(x, y), prp_r, prp_g)
qm2 <- data.frame()
for(i in seq_along(prpList){
qm2.fit <- fitQmapQUANT(r_df[i],r_df[i+1], qstep=0.01,nboot=1,wet.day=TRUE) 
qm2[[i]] <- doQmapQUANT(r_df[i+1],qm2.fit,type="tricub")
}
```

Something along these lines may do the trick.